# robocopy can’t find newly zipped file for copy

Tags: batch, robocopy, winzip

I am working with a batch file that is being used to copy files from several remote servers to one central repository using robocopy. I am trying to zip the contents of a folder and then copy it but robocopy then returns the message:

"Warning: name not matched: z:\ExamplerServer\folder1 Error: No files were found for this action that match your criteria - nothing to do. (z:\ExampleServer\folder1\ExampleServerDailyBackup.zip)"

I am able to copy zipped files from other folders with out a problem....what is the reason that robocopy isn't able to find the newly created zip file for copy? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

here is a snippet of the batch file:

```
@echo off 

::set logging path w/date stamp 
set log="y:\Backup Logs\%%adaily-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%.log" 

::using txt file for list of port servers to backup 
for /f "tokens=* delims= "  %%a in (ExampleServers.txt) do ( 

    ::mapping source and destination paths 
    net use z: \\%%a\d$  
    net use y: "\\ExampleServer\folderA\folder B" 
    z: 
    ::robocopy file copy parameters 
    wzzip -ex z:\folder1\%%aDailyBackup.zip z:\folder1 
    robocopy z:\folder1\ y:\%%a /Z /R:1 /LOG:%log% 
    wzzip -ex -s -ycAES128 y:\%%a\%%aDailyBackup.zip y:\%%a 
    c: 
    ::delete mapping after each file copy 
    net use z: /delete 
    net use y: /delete 
) 

exit
```

Comment: I love bat files :)

Please, use <br> in your problem description at the end of the lines to separate them. See the result in preview box before posting.

Comment: Use "echo.something to show %variable%" command to "debug" your bat, and "pause" to do it step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the fly in the ointment.  the problem was with where I was trying to have robocopy copy the .zip file from.  It turns out that I was telling robocopy to try calling from one level too deep.